# Strong Markov property of the mirror coupling

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $B=(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}^d$ starting from $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with $y \neq x$, and $R$ be the mirror reflection with respect to the $(d-1)$-dimensional hyperplane $H:= \{z \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid |z-x|=|z-y|\}$ bisecting $x$ and $y$. We define $W$ by
\begin{align*} 
W_t=
\begin{cases}
RB_t,\quad &t<\tau,\\
B_t,\quad &t \ge \tau.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Here, $\tau=\inf\{t>0 \mid B_t \in H\}$. Because $R$ is an orthogonal matrix, $W_t$ is also a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion starting from $y$. The pair $(B,W)$ is often called the mirror coupling of Brownian moitons.

**My question**

The mirror coupling $(B,W)$ is a strong Markov process on $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$?

This  claim seems to be true. However, I don't quite get it.

Please let me know if you have an simple reason.

Comment: I don't think one can do simple reasoning with the Strong Markov property. You will have to go through the details, unfortunately. Have you seen a proof of the SMP for  Brownian motion? You can see the proof of theorem 0.2 [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~mdamron6/teaching/Fall_2017/notes/Math_7244_week_5.pdf)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you for your comment. I think $(B,W)$ is obtained by connecting two strong Markov processes on $\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But I don't know how that helps, since the processes are coupled. We will have to think more about this one. By the way, your question is fascinating : where did you get the idea from that this is Strong Markov? Also which text are you consulting?

Comment: I had two ideas, apart from going direct : one is that every Feller process is a Strong Markov process, by a result in Partszch and Schilling. The process you have looks like a Feller process to me. The next is to show that the resulting processes' probability distributions satisfy the martingale problem for a specific pair of functions, and then there's a result in Karatzas and Shreve about these probability distributions determining a unique Strong Markov Process. That's more involved, though.